# Why does openssl s_client fail to get the server certificate of my AWS postgres endpoint?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I wanted to check the server certificate used by my AWS RDS postgres instance. I executed below command.

```
openssl s_client -connect <db_domain_name>:5432 -showcerts
```

It gave me the output below, which shows that the instance doesn't provide a certificate.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140121607600016:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
....
....
```

But if I try to connect to the database via `psql`, it shows me that it is using SSL.

```
psql (9.2.24, server 13.7)
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 13.0.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits: 128)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=>
```

How does psql establish the SSL connection without server providing a certificate? If the server actually provides a certificate, why does `openssl s_client` fail to retrieve it?

Comment: "why does openssl s_client fail to retrieve [the cert]"? The cert is received as part of the TLS handshake, but "handshake fail[ed]" so it wasn't received. Although Postgres uses TLS, it does NOT do so immediately on connection, as your command is attempting; instead it does a postgres-specific protocol first and THEN starts TLS. Many other protocols also do this. OpenSSL `s_client` supports 'starttls' for _some_ such protocols, but only 1.1.1 up includes postgres. Get up-to-date OpenSSL and use `s_client -starttls postgres ...`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks!. Please post as answer, so I can accept.

Comment: This is not programming or development, which has become the official scope as of about 3-4 years ago; that's why I didn't answer in the first place.